# How to store database data into a local variable for a connection system

Tags: php, database, pdo

I followed a youtube video to make my connection system, it work, but I don't really understand so I can't modify it. I would like to SELECT the current user id and the current user grade and store them into SESSION's vars. (Srry if my english is bad I can try to explain better in the comment section)

Here is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblClients
(
    client_id           int         NOT NULL,
    nom             text        NOT NULL,
    prenom          text        NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(320)    NOT NULL,
    username        text        NOT NULL,
    passwrd         text        NOT NULL,
    grade           text        NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

Here is my PHP PDO Code:

```
<?php
include 'includes/include_account.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $userConnected = false;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblClients WHERE username = :username AND passwrd = :passwrd";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
      array(
        'username' => $_POST["username"], 'passwrd' => $_POST["password"]
      )
    );
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if ($count > 0)
    {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["currentUserName"] = $_POST['username'];
      /*$_SESSION["currentUserGrade"] = 'account grade';*/
      /*$_SESSION["currentUserId"] = 'account id';*/
      $userConnected = true;
    }

    if(!$userConnected)
    {
      header('Location: ../../connexion.php');
    }

}
else if(isset($_SESSION["currentUserName"]))
{

}
else
{
  header('Location: ../../connexion.php');
}




?>
```

Comment: No no no, don't close this question, the duplicate doesn't answer my question

Comment: it does. you need to **fetch** the selected row. it would contain all the user info

Comment: Yes it will contain all the user info but after this how to put for exemple the email to a specific SESSION var and the ID the an other specific SESSION var